Prevent Material UI ModalUnstyled from 'closing' backdrop
I am using Material UI ModalUnstyled
Currently, when the 'showSpinner' prop is true, a <Spinner /> overlays the modal content. The problem is: When the user clicks on the backdrop of the Modal, the backdrop closes... I do not want this to happen and I am not sure how to prevent this
export const Modal = ({
                          children,
                          show,
                          onClickClose,
                          showSpinner,
                      }: ModalProps) => {
    const ariaForId = `:modal-id-aria-${guidGenerator()}:`

    const BackdropUnstyled = React.forwardRef<
        HTMLDivElement,
        { open?: boolean; className: string }
    >((props, ref) => {
        // @ts-ignore
        // https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/32882
        const {ownerState, open, className, ...other} = props;
        return <div
            className={clsx({'MuiBackdrop-open': open}, 'modal-backdrop', className)}
            ref={ref}
            {...other}>
            <BlurOverlay onClick={!showSpinner ? onClickClose : () => {}}/>
        </div>
    });

    return <ModalUnstyled
        aria-labelledby={ariaForId}
        aria-describedby={ariaForId}
        open={show}
        onClose={!showSpinner ? onClickClose : () => {}}
        className={'modal-container'}
        slots={{backdrop: BackdropUnstyled}}>
        <div role={'dialog'}>
            {showSpinner && <div/>}
            <div>
                {showSpinner && <Spinner/>}
                {children}
            </div>
        </div>
    </ModalUnstyled>
}

interface BlurOverlayProps extends PropsWithOptionalChildren {
    classes?: string | string[],
    onClick?: () => void,
}

export const BlurOverlay = ({
                                children,
                                classes,
                                onClick,
                            }: BlurOverlayProps) => {
    const [domElementForBlur, setDomElementForBlur] = useState<HTMLElement | null>(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        const elementToApplyBlurTo = document.getElementById('modal-container-anchor')
        if (elementToApplyBlurTo) {
            elementToApplyBlurTo!.setAttribute('style', 'backdrop-filter: url(#svgBlur); backdrop-filter: blur(5px); width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0')
            setDomElementForBlur(elementToApplyBlurTo)
        }

        return () => {
            if (elementToApplyBlurTo) elementToApplyBlurTo.setAttribute('style', '')
        }
    }, [])

    const _onClick = () => {
        if (domElementForBlur) domElementForBlur.setAttribute('style', '')
        if (onClick) onClick()
    }

    return <div
        className={clsx('blur-overlay-container', classes)}
        onClick={_onClick}>
        {children}
    </div>
}


I thought by making the execution of onClickClose conditional, like so !showSpinner ? onClickClose : () => {} I would prevent the Backdrop from closing, but there seems to be something happening with the <ModalUnstyled /> which I do no understand.
